# how to loop through object and check if it has another object as an attribute with a name "test__c"

Tags: javascript, loops, object, contains

I have an object as below which contains 3 other objects

```
var masterObject = {
                     test__a:{},
                     test__b:{},
                     test__c{}
                   }
```

Here i want to check if my `marsterObject` contains `test__c`. Please let me know how can i check it in Javascript.

Comment: `masterObject.hasOwnProperty("test__c")`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var masterObject = {
  test__a: {},
  test__b: {},
  test__c: {}
}

console.log(masterObject.hasOwnProperty("test__c"));
console.log(masterObject.hasOwnProperty("test__d"));
```

Answer (score 0):

test__c is a property of masterObject and can be accessed with the dot notation,

```
if(masterObject.test__c !== undefined && masterObject.test__c !== null){
 // do something ith test__c
}
```

if, the property, that you want to check, itself could vary, then use the associative array synxtax,

```
if(masterObject[test__c] !== undefined && masterObject[test__c] !== null){
     // do something ith test__c
 }
```